# need sticky header and footer when content is too large

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, footer, sticky-footer

I created a custom table using `div`'s (was only solution due  too complex behaviour). But I have a problem with the header and the footer.

The table `html`is basically simple:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

What I need is the following: when the content inside the table is not too large to be viewed without scrollbar the header will just be at the top and the footer just below the content (so not sticky to the bottom of the container).
But when the content of the table expands (either on page load with new data or by expanding some table content using `javascript`/`jQuery`) I need the header to stick at the top of the container and the footer stick at the bottom of the container while the content can scroll without overlapping the header/footer.

I searched around a lot on this but haven't found a decent solution, is there a way to solve this (as simple as possible) using `css` and/or `javascript`/`jquery`?

**Edit**
Here a basic sample of what I mean: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVLyf/)

If you click the `span` in the example the header and footer should become fixed at the top and bottom of the container. But how do I detect the increase in size?

Comment: you can `position:fixed` of header and footer using css. find height div.content than using jquery given scroll on the this Div.

Comment: @Jigs since the table can be placed anywhere inside the page and the content can be dynamically expanded (so scrollbars are shown without a `scroll event` being triggered), I don't see how this helps. How can I 'catch' the resizing of the content?

Comment: looking for somthing like this : http://jsfiddle.net/kCZPF/7/

Comment: this might give you an idea http://jsfiddle.net/8BcPp/1/ sorry its mootools not started using jquery but think I might try.

Comment: @Dampsquid Not just quite there yet. I updated my question with an example could you check it out (it's `jQuery`)?

Comment: @Jigs the scrollbar should be positioned around the table itself. Look at my question for an example.

Comment: the timer checks the need for the scroll by comparing the offsetHeight and the scrollHeights periodically, I see your example adds/removes more content, I just resized the browser to to force the content to grow, but ive updated fiddle as well http://jsfiddle.net/8BcPp/2/

Comment: @Dampsquid Almost there, but as in my example, the scrollbar should be around the table itself and the height should be determined by the surrounding container. And any ideas on how to manage the timer when multiple tables are on one page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) + [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) = [DISCO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS-RsIzb78U&feature=youtube_gdata)

Basically ([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7Tqy/2/)):

```
function placeHeader(){ 
    var $table  = $('#table');  
    var $header = $('#header'); 
    if ($table.offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
        $header.offset({top: $(window).scrollTop()});
    } else { 
        $header.offset({top: $table.offset().top}); 
    }    
}

$(window).scroll(placeHeader);
```

In other words, if the top of the table is above the scrollTop, then position the header at scrollTop, otherwise put it back at the top of the table. Depending on the contents of the rest of the site, you might also need to check if you have scrolled all the way past the table, since then you don't want the header to stay visible.

And don't forget about [`$(window).height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) for doing the same with the footer.

Comment: I get what you mean but how to detect changes in size dynamically? See my updated question for an example of what I mean. (PS I didn't downvote)

Comment: I don't know of any direct way to detect changes in size. Best would be to call `placeHeader()` after every action which might change the table, for instance `$(this).next().toggle(0,placeHeader);`. A less elegant, but easier solution, is to simply call `placeHeader()` at regular intervals: `setInterval(placeHeader,100);`. If you really need to *detect changes in size*, then you can use `setInterval` to monitor the current height and compare it to the previous height.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete violation of the language's semantics, and as a result it likely completely destroys all accessibility.  Use an HTML table instead.

```
<table id="mahTable" summary="some descriptive summary">
    <caption>This descriptive data visually appears outside your table.</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Header Cell</th><th>Other header cell</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>data 1</td><td>data 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td colspan="2">footer here</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

To say this is not possible in your current code/programming means you entirely need to rethink your approach.  Get the HTML correct first and then figure out presentation later.  If you are too busy fretting over presentation before you have addressed the needs or structure of your content then your presentation will likely fail anyways.

Comment: thanks for the input but the contents of the table consists of different (also too complex) 'inner tables', too much overlapping cells/rows and has different animated show hide functionalities (all needed and discussed specs of the application), which led to the decision of using `div` based table over standard table. (normally I would be all for using standard table)