# Floating elements on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins

I was wondering how sites like Facebook, with their timeline feature, float a certain element (usually a menu bar, or sometimes a social plugin, etc) when the user has scrolled past a point such that the top of the element is off the screen, etc.

This could be seen as a more general JavaScript (jQuery?) event firing when the user has scrolled to a certain element, or scrolled down a certain number of pixels.

Obviously it would require toggling the CSS property from:

```
#foo { position: relative; }
```

to

```
#foo { position: fixed; }
```

Or with jQuery, something like:

```
$('#foo').css('position', 'fixed');
```

Another way I have seen this implemented is with blogs, where a popup will be called when you reach the bottom, or near the bottom of a page. My question is, what is firing that code, and could you link or provide some syntax/ semantics/ examples?

Edit: I'm seeing some great JS variants coming up, but as I am using jQuery, I think the plugin mentioned will do just nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/RWJhM/2/

In this example, I'm using `document.onscroll = function(){ //Scroll event }` to detect a scroll event on the document.

I'm then calculating the percentage of the page scrolled based on it's height. `(document.body.scrollTop * 100 / (document.body.clientHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight))`.

`document.body.scrollTop` being the number of pixels scrolled from the top, `document.body.clientHeight` being the height of the entire document and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` being the visible portion of the document, a.k.a. the viewport.

Then you can compare this value to a target percentage, an execute `JavaScript`. `if(currentPercentage > targetPercentage)`...

Here's the whole thing:

```
document.onscroll = function(){
        var targetPercentage = 80;
        var currentPercentage = (document.body.scrollTop * 100 / (document.body.clientHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight));
        console.log(currentPercentage);
        if(currentPercentage > targetPercentage){
            document.getElementById('pop').style.display = 'block';
            // Scrolled more than 80%
        } else {
            document.getElementById('pop').style.display = 'none';
            // Scrolled less than 80%
        }
    }
```

​If you prefer jQuery, here is the same example translated into everybody's favorite library: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/8NVS6/1/

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    var targetPercentage = 80;
    var currentPercentage = $(document).scrollTop() * 100 / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());
    if(currentPercentage > targetPercentage){
        $('#pop').css({display:'block'});
        //Scrolled more than 80%
    } else {
        $('#pop').css({display:'none'});
        //Scrolled less than 80%
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to handle the window.scroll event and determine if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page. Here is an example:

http://chrissilich.com/blog/load-more-content-as-the-user-reaches-the-bottom-of-your-page-with-jquery/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin that might help you in the right direction.
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 0):

I just answered basically the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9786399/1171043).  In that case it was a table and its header, and the basic idea is like this:

```
function placeHeader(){ 
    var $table  = $('#table');  
    var $header = $('#header'); 
    if ($table.offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
        $header.offset({top: $(window).scrollTop()});
    } else { 
        $header.offset({top: $table.offset().top}); 
    }    
}

$(window).scroll(placeHeader);
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7Tqy/2/).

Quoting myself:

> In other words, if the top of the table is above the scrollTop, then
>   position the header at scrollTop, otherwise put it back at the top of
>   the table. Depending on the contents of the rest of the site, you
>   might also need to check if you have scrolled all the way past the
>   table, since then you don't want the header to stay visible.

To answer your question directly, it is triggered by checking the `scrollTop` against either the position of an element, or `the height of the document` `minus` `the height of the viewport` (for the scrolled to bottom use case). This check is done every time the scroll event is fired (bound using `$(window).scroll(...)`).